# Why should Firebase cloud functions triggered by Realtime database be located in us-central1 region

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

Firebase cloud functions [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations) says that background functions triggered by Realtime database should always be located in `us-central1` region. It doesn't explain why, though.
Is it also applicable to the cases when Realtime database is located in Europe or Australia? Or is it ok to put this type of functions closer to Realtime database location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*firebaser here*

tl;dr: that doc page is outdated, so I filed a request to update it.

You should should select the Cloud Function region closest to where your Realtime Database is hosted to avoid cross-region traffic.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/projects/locations#rtdb-locations

Realtime Database was only available in `us-central1` for a long time, but is available in `europe-west1` and `asia-southeast1` now too. We probably forgot to update the documentation at that point, so... thanks for catching it.